# Android. Как сделать ToggledButton с ripple-эффектом

Tags: android, button, android-style, android-button, toggle

Подскажите как сделать риппл-эффект
на ToggledButton

```
<ToggleButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/toggle_button"
    android:textOff="Не готов"
    android:textOn="Не готов"
    android:theme="@style/customActivityStyle.DatsunToggledButton" />

<style name="customActivityStyle.DatsunToggledButton" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/design_gray_color_design</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@color/design_gray_color_design" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@color/design_red_color" />
</selector>
```

Как я понимаю, не нужно задавать бэкграунд. 
Но в то же самое время не понимаю как задать цвет для состояния нажатия?